# Error in logs: kernel[0]: Validation failed, dataSuffix

Tags: error, iwork, logs, console, kernel

I've the following errors in my system logs when running Pages (or any iWork app):

```
Aug  4 19:01:09 kernel[0]: Validation failed, dataSuffix: 
Aug  4 19:01:09 kernel[0]: b9 d5 6f e2 28 3e b9 48 82 12 80 33 10 14 01 9c 06 00 2b 20 8a e1 64 b1 da f5 90 a3 af ba 32 52 83 4a d6 25 08 d3 88 72 39 a5 2a 39 5e a0 f7 77 66 bb 
Aug  4 19:01:09 kernel[0]: vnode_validate_compressed_file_Type4 error: 22
Aug  4 19:01:09 kernel[0]: Validation failed, dataSuffix: 
Aug  4 19:01:09 kernel[0]: b9 d5 6f e2 28 3e b9 48 82 12 80 33 10 14 01 9c 06 00 2b 20 8a e1 64 b1 da f5 90 a3 af ba 32 52 83 4a d6 25 08 d3 88 72 39 a5 2a 39 5e a0 f7 77 66 bb 
Aug  4 19:01:09 kernel[0]: vnode_validate_compressed_file_Type4 error: 22
```

What is causing that, how to debug that and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These errors are reported by kernel and are caused by corruptive file compression in [HFS+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus).

Suggestions:

- Please run Disk Utility to Verify Disk for any file-system inconsistency (as well as Verify and Repair Disk Permissions),
- If you're using any compression software tool, you may consider to upgrade it or remove it (e.g. [Clusters](http://latenitesoft.com/clusters/)),
- Run Console and check 'Diagnostic and Usage Info -> User/System Diagnostic Reports' for any kernel or software crashes which could potentially cause that problems,
- Re-install completely the software which is failing (e.g. Pages),
- Use [Time Machine](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1427) to recover the files from when it was working,
- This could be some hardware issue, please run S.M.A.R.T. tests for your HDD to find any issues or bad sectors,
- This you're using SSD, it could have been heavily used (as it has quite short life span in comparision to HDD) or you could be using some bad quality product,
- If anything won't help, you may try to make an appointment with [Genius Bar](http://www.apple.com/retail/geniusbar/).